# Splitting $f * 2^e$ Across Digits

Tags: algorithms

I have a number $v = f * 2^e$ where $f$ has up to nine digits, and $0 \le e \le 3$. I'm interested in splitting, for example, $v=123456789 * 2^2$ into three parts: $f * 2^2 \to 493, 827, 156$.

The intuitive (to me) operations are:

- $2^2 * v / 10^6$ % $10^3 = 493$
- $2^2 * v / 10^3$ % $10^3 = 827$
- $2^2 * v / 10^0$ % $10^3 = 156$

But I know (from an algorithm paper I'm reading) that you can do:

- $v / (10^3 / 2^2) / 10^3 = 493$
- $v / (10^3 / 2^2)$ % $10^3 = 827$
- $v$ % $(10^3 / 2^2) * 2^2 = 156$

The equivalence of the operations are not apparent to me. Can someone provide some clarity about how the operations are equivalent?

If down voting, please indicate to me in a comment how to improve my question or a more appropriate place to ask my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which is $v$?  Is it $123456789$ or $493827156$?  If you are using integer divide, splitting it into three pieces is as easy as:
$v/10^6$ to get the top three,
$v\%10^3$ to get the bottom three and
$(v/10^3)\%10^3$ to get the middle three.

The paper is using $v=123456789$ because it divides the modulus by $2^2$. They will work because $2^2$ divides evenly into $10^3$.  If it didn't, it would be better to multiply $v$ by $2^2$ before doing the divides.

Your operations will be close for $v=123456789$ but not correct.  $v/10^6=123$, so when you multiply it by $2^2$ you get $492$, which carries through the rest unchanged.  You lose the carry because you divided before multiplying by $4$.

Comment: $v = f * 2^e$. For $f=123456789$ and $e=2$, $v = 493827156$. I hope that makes it clearer. So, you need need to factor in the exponent part like I did. But I see your point that multiplying by $2^2$ before doing the divides / modulus eliminates the need for a second modulus.

Comment: As well as preventing errors from integer rounding.

Comment: Thanks, after seeing your answer, I was able to completely reason through the way the paper does it.